# R, Como calcular a média de uma variavel x para cada grupo de cada uma das outras variaveis

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

Eu queria fazer uma tabela mais ou menos desse jeito: Uma coluna com as variáveis nominais e seus grupos e outra coluna com a média de uma variável x para cada grupo de cada variável.

Com o dplyr eu consigo(sei) fazer isso mas apenas se eu fizer um `group_by()` de cada vez.

Exemplo: Digamos que no dataset mtcars a minha variável x seja `mpg` enquanto que minhas variáveis qualitativas sejam `vs,am, gear,carb`.

```r
mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>% summarise(mean(mpg))

mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(mean(mpg))

mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(mean(mpg))

mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarise(mean(mpg))
```

Com isso eu tenho a média de mpg para cada grupo em cada variavel mas o que estou procurando é uma forma de, seja pelo dplyr ou por outro pacote fazer essas quatro coisas de uma vez só, de modo que com esse único output eu consiga uma tabela através de algo como um `knit::kable()`

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Para ter sua pergunta respondida adequadamente, forneça um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Confira [esta postagem do Meta sobre como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformate para formato longo e depois agrupe e calcule as médias todas de uma vez.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, vs, am, gear, carb) %>%
  pivot_longer(-mpg) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta está com a *tag* `dplyr` e [Rui Barradas já forneceu uma resposta ótima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/518496/117168). Mas como a questão cita "seja pelo dplyr ou por outro pacote", eis duas alternativas, para ficar registrado:

**R base**

A função `aggregate` calcula sumários por grupo. Assim como no caso de usar dplyr, os dados precisam estar em formato longo:

```
# Empilha as variáveis selecionadas e adiciona valores de mpg
dados <- stack(mtcars, select = c("vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
dados$mpg <- mtcars$mpg

aggregate(mpg ~ ind + values, dados, mean)
#>     ind values      mpg
#> 1    vs      0 16.61667
#> 2    am      0 17.14737
#> 3    vs      1 24.55714
#> 4    am      1 24.39231
#> 5  carb      1 25.34286
#> 6  carb      2 22.40000
#> 7  gear      3 16.10667
#> 8  carb      3 16.30000
#> 9  gear      4 24.53333
#> 10 carb      4 15.79000
#> 11 gear      5 21.38000
#> 12 carb      6 19.70000
#> 13 carb      8 15.00000
```

Alternativamente, usando o pacote *reshape2* para alterar o formato dos dados:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ variable + value,
  data = reshape2::melt(mtcars, "mpg", c("vs", "am", "gear", "carb")),
  FUN = mean)
```

**data.table**

Assim como *dplyr*, opera com paradigma "dividir/aplicar". Possui as funções `melt` e `dcast` (equivalentes às do pacote *reshape2*) para alterar o formato dos dados.

```
library(data.table)

dados <- melt(as.data.table(mtcars), "mpg", c("vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))

dados[, mean(mpg), .(variable, value)]
```